# jquery scroll in section

Tags: jquery, scroll

With the following HTML :

```
<body>
<header>...</header>
<div class="do-sectionScroll1">...</div>
<div class="do-sectionScroll2">...</div>
<div class="do-sectionScroll3">...</div>
<footer>...</footer>
</body>
```

I want free scroll in `<header>` and `<footer>` but I want to lock it into do-sectionScroll. So the user is obliged to scroll `<div>` after `<div>` like one page scroll.

I didn't find any plugin to do that. Many plugins are one page scroll, not `<div>` scroll.

How can I do that ?

EDIT :

I created a logical example on http://jsfiddle.net/promo/mb8nh6sh/3/ of what I'm trying to do...

EDIT 2 :

What I'm trying to do should be something like this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

 $(document).on('scroll', function(){



    /*

    IF SCROLL TO THE BOTTOM

        if $(window).scrollTop() < header.height

             do nothing special


        if $(window).scrollTop() > header.height

            scroll to do-sectionScroll1


         if $(window).scrollTop() go to bottom AND do-sectionScroll1 reached

             scroll to do-sectionScroll2


         if $(window).scrollTop() go to bottom AND do-sectionScroll2 reached

             scroll to do-sectionScroll3


         if $(window).scrollTop() go to bottom AND footer reached

             do nothing special


     IF SCROLL TO THE TOP

         if $(window).scrollTop() go to top AND do-sectionScroll3 reached

             scroll to do-sectionScroll2


         if $(window).scrollTop() go to top AND do-sectionScroll2 reached

             scroll to do-sectionScroll1


         if $(window).scrollTop() go to top AND header reached

             do nothing special


         etc ... 



    */


};


});
```

Comment: how about **[this plugin](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage)**

Comment: I didn't tested this plugin in particular, but I tested jquery scroll section plugin and another one... The problem is that if the header and footer aren't encapsulated in div, at the first scrolling my first div is shown but I'm not able to go to the top of the page because header is not in a scroll "page" div.

Comment: Can you post complete html or a fiddle to work around with?

Comment: I provide you a little example with jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/promo/mb8nh6sh/1/ If it's not clear feel free to ask me for more details.. Thanks

Comment: I reckon the effect should be similar to this? http://ataredo.com/